# PHP Remove all punctuation, space and numeric in beginning string

Tags: php, regex

I have alot of string like this :

```
[
  '01.671.324.0-445.000 JL.RAYA BANJARAN',
  '02.382.643.1-008.000 RUKO BUARAN'
  '31.765.446.5-433.000 JL.SURYA UTAMA',
  '010694040059000 SUMMITMAS 1, 11TH FLOOR,',
  '000 118 8 092 000 THE MANOR BUILDING',
  '013862305401000 JL.RAYA SERANG KM.71 DESA TAMBAK,'
]
```

How to strip out all the numeric, space, and punctuation in beginning string.?
The result of them is start in alphabet each. 
I want to preg_replace them like this:

```
[
  'JL.RAYA BANJARAN',
  'RUKO BUARAN'
  'JL.SURYA UTAMA',
  'SUMMITMAS 1, 11TH FLOOR,',
  'THE MANOR BUILDING',
  'JL.RAYA SERANG KM.71 DESA TAMBAK,'
]
```

Sorry, forgot to attach regex that I try : `preg_replace('/^[0-9]+\. +/', '', $string);`

As you can see, that is an adress string.
I got again a case which string like this

```
013123305401000 16TH FLOOR, MIDPLAZA 2 BUILDING
```

TO

```
16TH FLOOR, MIDPLAZA 2 BUILDING
```

Please advise

Comment: Please share your attempts. You're already mentioned what function to use.

Answer (score 1):

The regex you're trying would match one or more digits, followed by a single dot, then one or more spaces and that's it. If you want to remove all digits, spaces, and punctuation, you need to put all these characters inside square brackets:

```
preg_replace('/^[0-9.\- ]+/', '', $string);
```

For the future, here's a great tool for testing all your regular expressions: https://regex101.com/

Comment: Thanks buddy, please see my update

Comment: This will remove `16` in the last example `013123305401000 16TH FLOOR, MIDPLAZA 2 BUILDING`